# Why does this code to randomize a list of song names generate a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, function, random, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a program that receives from the user 12 song titles and then forms a set list in a random order. I have used the `gets()` function and memory allocation so that the input is placed into an array like this:

```
 argv[0] = song1, argv[1] = song2, argv[2] = song3 (etc.).
```

There seems to be the common segmentation fault error when inputting the actual songs and then running it through the randomize and `createSetList()` functions. However, if one were to scrap the memory allocation and hard code instead it would work fine. By this I mean something like:

```
char *input[ SONG ] =
  { "song1", "song2", "song3", "song4",
      "song5", "song6", "song7", "song8",
        "song9", "song10", "song11", "song12", "song13" };
```

Although, my purpose is to have the user input the song titles during run time. What is the reason for a segmentation fault error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SONG 13
#define SETSIZE 5
// prototypes

void randomize( unsigned int wDeck[ SONG ] ); 
void createSetList( unsigned int wDeck[ SONG ], char *wFace[] ); 

int main( void ){

printf("Please enter the songs you want to play!\n");
printf("I will create the set list and randomize it for you!\n");


char input[100];
char *argv[ SONG ];
char *token;

 /*memory allocation for inputting song titles into a single array*/
 /*****memory allocation code starts here********/
 gets(input);
   token = strtok(input, " ");
     int i=0;
       while( token != NULL ) {
         argv[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
           strncpy(argv[i], token, strlen(token));
             i++;
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } 
       argv[i] = NULL; //argv ends with NULL
         /***memory allocation code ends here*****/

         unsigned int setList[ SONG ] = { 0 };
           srand( time( NULL ) ); // seed random-number generator
             randomize( setList ); // shuffle the list
                createSetList( setList, argv ); // create the setlist
 } //end of main





/*SHUFFLE FUNCTION*/
   void randomize( unsigned int wDeck[ SONG ] ){

     size_t column;
      size_t c;

 for ( c = 1; c <= SETSIZE; ++c ) {
     do {
       column = rand() % SONG;
         } while( wDeck[ column ] != 0 );

               wDeck[ column ] = c;}}

    /* Create Set List Function */
 void createSetList( unsigned int wDeck[ SONG ],  char *wFace[] ){

    size_t c;
     size_t column;

      for ( c = 1; c <= SETSIZE; ++c ) {

        for ( column = 0; column < SONG; ++column ) {

          if ( wDeck[ column ] == c ) {

             printf( "%s\n", wFace[ column ]); 
                }}}}
```

Comment: Any? Remember that `gets` have no bounds checking and have been a big source of security infractions. It has been deprecated since C99, and in the latest C11 standard have been obsoleted. Don't use it. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: `gets()` is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Where exactly crashes your program?

Comment: Remember that `fgets` includes the final `newline` in the input string. I would add more delimiting chars to the `strtok` calls, as `token = strtok(input, " \r\n");` and ditto the matching one at the end of the loop.

Comment: All wonderful comments. Much appreciated

Comment: Your indentation style is very confusing.  Did you invent it or were you taught this way?

Comment: See [Why is the `gets()` function so dangerous that it should never be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
strncpy(argv[i], token, strlen(token));
```

usage is wrong. You need to copy the terminating null byte also.

As we can see from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) of `strncpy()`

> The `strncpy()` function is similar, except that at most `n` bytes of `src` are copied.
>
> **Warning:** If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of `src`, the string placed in `dest` will not be null-terminated.

As mentioned in the comments my Mr **@ chqrlie** and explained in the [nice article](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.in/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) by **@Keith Thompson**, you should not be using `strncpy()`. To be on safer side, you can make use of [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to avoid the overhead (*and pitfalls*) of `malloc()`+ `strcpy()`.

Pseduo-code

```
 argv[i] = strdup(token);
```

will do the job in an efficient way. Remember, you need to still `free()` the returned pointer by `strdup()`.

Comment: Fantastic. This post really helped.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy()`.  Your example is a good illustration of why `strncpy()` is error prone.  In your case, either use `memcpy(argv[i], token, strlen(token)+1);` or even simpler, use `argv[i] = strdup(token);`

Comment: @chqrlie really appreciate leaving the comment. Updated my answer. However, 1) the point was using `strlen()+1`, without which `memcpy()` is __as dangerous__ as `strncpy()`. 2) is that the only reason you marked my answer as _"This answer is not useful"_?

Comment: My rant on the subject of `strncpy()`: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Comment: @Keith Thompson: kudos for this article, I fully agree with you, especially with the conclusion: *I see far more incorrect uses of it than correct uses*.  Therefore, I never skip an occasion to warn newbie and experienced programmers about this bear-trap.  Other ones on my list include: `strtok()`, `feof()`, `scanf()` and friends, `do/while`... so many incorrect uses of all these!

Comment: @chqrlie: Something else I see used incorrectly far more often than correctly is multi-character literals like `'ab'`. They're of type `int` and have an implementation-defined value; cases where they're actually useful are extremely rare. But I often see new C programmers confuse them with string literals.

Comment: `memcpy` is not as dangerous as `strncpy()`.  Read Keith's article and appreciate why `strncpy()` is dangerous and should be avoided.  `memcpy` can be used safely here, just as `strcpy(argv[i], token);` would have been.  You know the destination is large enough since you just allocated to the correct size. Passing the length of the source string as a third argument to  `strncpy()` shows a complete misunderstanding of this function.  Adding 1 to that fixes the behaviour, but does not teach the OP anything useful.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: you are correct, multi character character constants should have been deprecated a long time ago.  Java does not have them, and correctly warns about this in their spec, C++ still has them, beyond all logic.

Comment: @Sourav: I down voted your answer because you do not sufficiently deter the OP from using `strncpy()`, even as you give all the relevant information.  From his reaction, he might still think `strncpy()` is the right tool, where it is not.  Modify your answer to not use `strncpy()`, and I will remove the down vote.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for updating me. Nice article, indeed.

Comment: @chqrlie I see the point. Stand corrected. Updated my answer.